# How to change integers in to Date R

Tags: r, integer

Hi i got a quick question In R,

We can convert characters to dates for example

```
v <- c(2008101, 20081202, 20081103)
date <- as.Date(as.character(v), format("%Y%m%d"));date
```

But how can I convert `v<- c(200801, 200802)` to `2008-01` and `2008-02`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something simple like:

```
##Give each entry a date
v = paste0(v, "01")
##Convert as before
date = as.Date(as.character(v), format("%Y%m%d"));
```

You could even write a little function to do this automatically:

```
to_date = function(v) {
  v = as.character(v)

  missing_day = nchar(v) < 7
  v[missing_day] = paste0(v[missing_day], "01")
  as.Date(v, format("%Y%m%d"))
}

##Last value is missing the date
v = c(2008101, 20081202, 20081103, 200811)
to_date(v)
```

Comment: I think the desired result is `2008-01`, but your solution gives me `2008-01-01`. Thoughts?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I suppose it comes down to what and how the OP uses the date. When I'm in this situation I don't usually care about the day (for example plotting of 100 years).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative:

```
foo <- function(x){
  x <- as.Date(as.character(x), format("%Y%m%d"))
  newDates <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(x), "-"), "[", -2)
  sapply(newDates, function(x) paste(x[1],x[2],  sep="-"))
}

> foo(v)
[1] "2008-01" "2008-02" "2008-03"
```